# How to Hide Play button in Firefox 12 HTML 5 Video

Tags: firefox, html5-video

Firefox 12 now adds a Play button to HTML5 videos when Autoplay = false.

http://www.browsomatic.com/2012/01/firefox-12-now-shows-large-play-button.html

Is there a way I can hide this Play button. I want to use my own play button?

Comment: uuh. ugly one! i guess you cannot remove it, because there's no way to change the custom controls of each browser (as far as i know). so i guess you have to build your own controls

Answer (score 0):

Yo, In the meantime why don't you just lay an image over it w/ your own play button? That way you hide it. It's kinda of hack but it'll work.

Comment: That's a great idea, Nickdog, considering it was mine and I just told you about it at your cube. I'd ask Keith but he's in Rome. I think I'll go ask Mozilla directly how to do this and if they can't, maybe they can add an option to disable the play button in Firefox 13.